# How to change Serilog LogLevel at runtime for injected instance

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, asp.net-core, serilog

Framework: .NET Core 2.1

I'm using Elasticsearch configuration for Serilog as described in the code below:

**Startup.cs**

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().Enrich.FromLogContext()
                             .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(Configuration.GetSection("ElasticSearchURL").Value))
                             {
                                 AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
                                 MinimumLogEventLevel = Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Error
                             }).CreateLogger();
    services.AddSingleton(Log.Logger);
```

Is it possible to change the log level at runtime for injected instances of Logger?

```
private readonly ILogger<EmailService> _logger;
public EmailService(ILogger<EmailService> logger)
{
     _logger = logger;
}

public async Task<Result> Send(Email email)
{
    // CHANGE LOG LEVEL TO LOGINFORMATION HERE
    _logger.LogInformation("MESSAGE");
}
```

Comment: some relevant info in https://gitter.im/serilog/serilog atm (no, I can't summarise, and I'll delete this message at some point after you ack it by upvoting the comment)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an option in Serilog to change log file parameters in runtime, the same way LogLevel can be changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598428/is-there-an-option-in-serilog-to-change-log-file-parameters-in-runtime-the-same)

Answer (score 8):

Instead of setting the minimum log level in the Elasticsearch options, would you be able to set it at the Logger level? If you're able to instead do something like

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Error()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(Configuration.GetSection("ElasticSearchURL").Value))
    {
        AutoRegisterTemplate = true
    }).CreateLogger();
```

*then* you'd be able to use a LoggingLevelSwitch to control the minimum level, like this:

```
var levelSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch();
levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = Serilog.Events.LogLevelEvent.Error;

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(levelSwitch)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(Configuration.GetSection("ElasticSearchURL").Value))
    {
        AutoRegisterTemplate = true
    }).CreateLogger();
```

You'd need to have something like a singleton for your instance of the LoggingLevelSwitch to inject along with your ILogger.