# Is there an option in Serilog to change log file parameters in runtime, the same way LogLevel can be changed?

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

With Serilog in asp.net core you can change the log level in runtine by using

```
MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(SeriLogLevelSwitch).
```

Is there a similar way to do this with `LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.File(...)`

For instance i need to change the configuration for log `fileSizeLimitBytes`, or `rollingInterval` withour restaring the service. Can this be achieved with Serilog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By pulling in the latest *Serilog.AspNetCore* you'll find a class called `ReloadableLogger`, constructed through the `CreateBootstrapLogger()` extension method:

```cs
// using Serilog;
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .WriteTo.File(...)
  .CreateBootstrapLogger();

// Optional but suggested:
Log.Logger = logger;

// Use the logger...

// Change parameters later on:
logger.Reload(lc => lc
  .WriteTo.File(...));
```

You might find that some interactions between `CreateBootstrapLogger()` and `UseSerilog(callback)` in ASP.NET Core trip things up a bit; if you use this technique, try the parameterless version of `UseSerilog()`.

`ReloadableLogger` has only just appeared and is focusing on a slightly different scenario, so you may still need to work through some awkwardness setting this up - YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for help. Worked fine with netstandard2.1 I see that there is no support for ReloadableLogger in netstandard2.0. Are there any plans to add it?

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up! Unfortunately `ReloadableLogger` relies on default interface implementations right now (just to keep the amount of code there manageable), and these only work on the CLR from .NET Core 3.1 and onwards. Could be something we revisit in the future, though.

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt I need this feature for Unity (netstandard2.0) so much! Can't have any static loggers due to limitation: controller classes are inited after configuration is set. NLog has option to reconfigure. Because it holds references to all loggers.

Comment: @AndersonDev the codebase behind `ReloadableLogger` is pretty small - grabbing the source code and filling in the missing interface implementations should be doable. HTH!

Comment: Similar answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72472963/configuring-serilog-before-configuration-is-ready