# Configuring Serilog before configuration is ready?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, serilog

I have a web api (.NET Core 3.1) which is using Serilog for logging. Serilog is added to the `IWebHostBuilder` quite early:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return WebHost
        .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseSerilog((context, configuration) =>
        {
            if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                configuration.WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Debug);
                return;
            }

            configuration.WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(TelemetryConverter.Traces, LogEventLevel.Error);
        });
}
```

This means (afaik) that I need to have already configured the logger at this point. So this is the very first thing I do in the main:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
        .CreateLogger();

    var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
    host.Run();
}
```

But the line `.ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)` requires the configuration to be set up. This is usually done in the `StartUp` (again, afaik) which has not yet been run at this time. Obviously I could move my `LoggerConfiguration` to later, but the `.UseSerilog` would be called before it was configured.

So how do I configure Serilog with `IConfugration`, when I haven't set it up yet?

Comment: might be relevant: https://nblumhardt.com/2020/10/bootstrap-logger/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@RubenBartelink pointed to a very good ressource in comment.

This is also described in the [Serilog for ASP.NET Core documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore).

In particular the [two-stage initialization part](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#two-stage-initialization), which states:

> **Two-stage initialization**
>
> The example at the top of this page shows how to configure Serilog immediately when the application starts.
>
> This has the benefit of catching and reporting exceptions thrown during set-up of the ASP.NET Core host.
>
> The downside of initializing Serilog first is that services from the ASP.NET Core host, including the `appsettings.json` configuration and dependency injection, aren't available yet.
>
> To address this, Serilog supports two-stage initialization. An initial "bootstrap" logger is configured immediately when the program starts, and this is replaced by the fully-configured logger once the host has loaded.
> To use this technique, first replace the initial `CreateLogger()` call with `CreateBootstrapLogger()`:
>
> ```cs
> using Serilog;
> using Serilog.Events;
>
> public class Program
> {
>     public static int Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
>             .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
>             .Enrich.FromLogContext()
>             .WriteTo.Console()
>             .CreateBootstrapLogger(); // <-- Change this line!
> ```
>
> Then, pass a callback to `UseSerilog()` that creates the final logger:
>
> ```cs
> public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
>     Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
>         .UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) => configuration
>             .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
>             .ReadFrom.Services(services)
>             .Enrich.FromLogContext()
>             .WriteTo.Console())
>         .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
>         {
>             webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
>         });
> ```
>
> It's important to note that the final logger completely replaces the bootstrap logger: if you want both to log to the console, for instance, you'll need to specify `WriteTo.Console()` in both places, as the example shows.
>
> **Consuming `appsettings.json` configuration**
>
> Using two-stage initialization, insert the `ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)` call shown in the example above. The JSON configuration syntax is documented in the Serilog.Settings.Configuration README.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I found something similar which I followed. That was definitely an improvement, but this seems like even more of an improvement :-)