# Add/remove serilog logging level overrides at run time

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

I am using Serilog in .Net 6 WebApi and the required serilog settings, including default logging level and few overrides, are currently being set via appsettings. However, I am looking for a way to dynamically add/remove logging level override for additional namespaces during runtime so that I can capture additional logs on demand for troubleshooting issues, without redeploying the application with setting changes. Is this possible? Any guidance available on how this can be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: If your API is hosted in Azure, then you can use an [Azure App Configuration polling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-aspnet-core?tabs=core6x) feature that will be periodically checking Azure app config using sentinel key/s. When change is detected, it will reload app configuration (you can select which keys) without restarting the web app itself. Do note, that the configuration refresh is triggered by the incoming requests to web app. No refresh will occur if the web app is idle.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But our APIs are hosted on private cloud.

Comment: Ever figure out a solution?

Comment: @Terry apparently Serilog also provides reloadable logger, if you use CreateBootStrapLogger instead of CreateLogger. Reloadable logger can be reconfigured on the fly. So you will have to combine this with a Custom Config Provider which can provide new configuration that you can subsequently use to reconfigure Serilog. I came to know about this only recently. So haven't implemented this yet.

Comment: Its available vis Serilog.Extensions.Hosting package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an option in Serilog to change log file parameters in runtime, the same way LogLevel can be changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598428/is-there-an-option-in-serilog-to-change-log-file-parameters-in-runtime-the-same)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom configuration provider in .NET Core which reads the configuration from Database. And you may need to implement Reload option as well. So when you update the database - your configuration will get updated. Here are some references which may help you.

1. [Implement a custom configuration provider in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-configuration-provider?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040)
2. [A Refreshable SQL Server Configuration Provider for .NET Core](https://mousavi310.github.io/posts/a-refreshable-sql-server-configuration-provider-for-net-core/)
3. [Creating a custom ConfigurationProvider for a Entity Framework Core source](https://ofpinewood.com/blog/creating-a-custom-configurationprovider-for-a-entity-framework-core-source)

Comment: ok. Couple of follow up questions.
1. Will I need to move all Serilog related configuration to new config provider OR can I still keep the default settings in appsettings and only load addon from another source. 
2. In standard classes, I can explicitly use OptionsMonitor or OptionsSnapshot to control the type of option reload behavior. How do we specify this so that Serilog knows that settings has to be reloaded?

Comment: Answer to your first question - I think you may be able to keep the existing settings in the config file and add-ons in the new configuration provider. I believe it will behave the same way any other provider works - so if you config two providers it will work as you expected right?

Comment: Answer to your second question - You may need to try it with your existing provider. If serilog doesn't support dynamic configuration it won't work. You can verify it by keeping the reload option and modify the settings and verify serilog is working with the new configuration.