# Serilog.Sinks.Map Generating Different Log Entries vs Standard ReadFrom.Configuration with exact same appsettings.json

Tags: serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

I was following code from [Hot-reload any Serilog sink](https://nblumhardt.com/2023/02/dynamically-reload-any-serilog-sink/), the result had a few issues.

I started off with this:

```cs
// Program.cs
builder.Host.UseSerilog( ( context, loggerConfig ) =>
{
    loggerConfig.ReadFrom.Configuration( context.Configuration );
} );
```

And two appsettings.json files that merge together...

**appsettings.json**

```js
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Override": {
            "FastEndpoints": "Warning",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "6",
            "System.Net.Http": "6",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware": "6", 
            "System": "Warning"
        }
    }
}
```

**appsettings.Development.json**

```js
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Override": {
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
            "Nexgen.Middleware.NexgenMiddleware": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "WriteTo": {
        "Console": { 
            "Name": "Console",
            "Args": {
                "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Exception}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running this as is inside VS Code debugging, I get the output I expect:

```
[15:23:43 INF] Starting Nexgen web host <s:Program>
[15:23:43 INF] Now listening on: https://localhost:7058 <s:Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime>
[15:23:43 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. <s:Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime>
[15:23:43 INF] Hosting environment: Development <s:Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime>
[15:23:43 INF] Content root path: C:\BTR\Camelot\Websites\Nexgen <s:Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime>
```

However, if all I do is swap out my `loggerConfig.ReadFrom.Configuration( context.Configuration );` with the code found in the blog post:

```cs
var configVersion = 0L;
builder.Host.UseSerilog( ( context, loggerConfig ) =>
{
    loggerConfig.WriteTo.Map(
        _ => Interlocked.Read( ref configVersion ),
        ( _, writeTo ) => writeTo.Logger( sub => sub.ReadFrom.Configuration( context.Configuration ) ),
        sinkMapCountLimit: 5
    );
} );

// snipped

var app = builder.Build();

ChangeToken.OnChange<object?>(
    () => app.Configuration.GetReloadToken(),
    _ => Interlocked.Increment( ref configVersion ),
    null
);
```

A few things are happening:

1. Upon site start up, I get ~25 log entries in Console.  With most of the extra ones coming from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` sources.
2. The `"Nexgen.Middleware.NexgenMiddleware": "Warning"` setting is not obeyed and `Information` items are still appearing.
3. After the site is running, if I go and toggle `"Nexgen.Middleware.NexgenMiddleware": "Warning"` to be `Information` and back to Warning, I'm still getting Information logs (note that the configVersion is incremented when I update my file).

I hadn't even really gotten into the appsettings.json edits and testing logger configuration reloads, but even just 'starting off' with this produced very different result logs using the exact same configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that minimum level overrides are applied at the very start of the logging pipeline, in e.g. the `Log.Information()` calls, to determine whether or not a `LogEvent` should be constructed and passed further through the pipeline.

In the case of `WriteTo.Logger()`, the level overrides in the sublogger are irrelevant, because it's the outer logger that performs the process above and determines whether an event should be created.

(I think the blog post should call out this caveat, I'll make an update over there.)

Comment: Will watch for post update.  Are the overrides not working on main logger b/c I didn't do a ReadFrom.Configuration on it before doing the WriteTo.Map?  Additionally, what is the recommended practice for updating overrides when you want to debug a 'new problem'?  Simply modify config and restart the application?  Maybe I'm hoping for more than I really need (ability to modify at runtime without app restart) and everyone simply modifies configuration and restarts app then debugs whatever problem may have presented itself.

Comment: What about comment (here)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74586600/add-remove-serilog-logging-level-overrides-at-run-time?noredirect=1#comment136107608_74586600] mentioning BootstrapLogger?  Haven't read through source code yet, but is that applicable?  I'd assume not since you wrote and probably would have remembered?? :)